# spray.io strange get/delete/detach directives behavior

Tags: scala, rest, spray

I have written the following code using spray routing directives:

```
path("goal" / Segment) { id =>
  get {
    detach(ec) {
      val goal = srv.find(id)
      complete(goal)
    }
  } ~
    delete {
      detach(ec) {
        srv.delete(id)
        complete(OK)
      }
    }
}
```

The problem is the execution path is strange. First it goes to 
get->detach->srv.find->complete 
then to 
delete -> detach -> srv.delete -> complete 
and then it comes back to 
 get->detach->... 
 and completes there. The issue is srv.delete is executed which is not a desired behavior because I loose data. Can anyone explain me this behavior and tell me how to fix it ?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I've had similar problems because the route wasn't sufficiently isolated, so later parts were getting evaluated. But the `delete` directive ought to protect against that. Does the same thing happen without the `detach`es?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't understand why but it seems that this modification works properly:

```
path("goal" / Segment) { id =>
  get {
    detach(ec) {
      val goal = srv.find(id)
      complete(goal)
    }
  } ~
  delete {
    detach(ec) {
      complete {
        srv.delete(id)  // here
        OK
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Examples in the documentation [here](http://spray.io/documentation/1.2.2/spray-routing/execution-directives/detach/#detach) shows only cases where after detach comes only complete/reject directive. Therefore I suspect it was tested only with these.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue, it looks like something related to Spray route DSL, I solved it adding the command in the path:

```
(get & path("goal" / Segment)) { id =>
  detach(ec) {
    val goal = srv.find(id)
    complete(goal)
  }
} ~
(delete & path("goal" / Segment)) { id =>
  detach(ec) {
    srv.delete(id)
    complete(OK)
  }
}
```

It would be nice to see another solution to be honest instead of having to always replicate the path but up to now this was the only thing which worked.

Comment: yes this one works fine but i dont like repetition here. i think i will stick to the solution above, still thanks:)